# How can I do this relational division query?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, relational-algebra

I want to do a relational division query. First, here is the structure of each table:

**Student**

```
id
name
```

**Course**

```
id
name
```

**Student_passed_course** (junction table that stores who passed which course)

```
id_student
id_course
```

Basically, what I want is to get the names of the students that have passed all the courses that exist in table `Course` using `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`, etc). I already implemented a solution using `NOT EXISTS`.

Also this is the equation I made.
[image: My relational algebra formula]

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on JOIN could be as follow:

```
SELECT s.name AS student_name, c.name as course_name FROM (
SELECT s_id, c_id, SUM(c_exists) AS c_exists, SUM(c_taken) as c_taken, SUM(c_exists)-SUM(c_taken) as not_taken FROM (
SELECT s.id as s_id, c.id as c_id, 1 as c_taken, 0 as c_exists FROM student s JOIN student_passed_course spc ON spc.id_student = s.id JOIN course c ON c.id = spc.id_course
UNION ALL
SELECT s.id as s_id, c.id as c_id, 0 as c_taken, 1 as c_exists FROM student s JOIN course c
) X group BY s_id, c_id) Y 
JOIN student s ON s.id = s_id JOIN course c ON c_id = c.id
WHERE not_taken = 1;
```

I don't know if this would be more or less efficient than your solution.